# Make UIDatePicker appear with the time when a static UITableViewCell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have an app where I want, by tapping a static `UITableViewCell` within a `UITableViewController`, a `UIDatePicker` **to pop up on the bottom of the screen**, that lets me pick the time(e.g. the hour, minute, and AM/PM).

Obviously, it would have to be **created completely programmatically** because

1. I want to hide it(when a button on the picker is pressed or
   somewhere outside the picker is tapped)
2. I can't add it to the View Controller. Any ideas?

Comment: show the code where you are adding the date picker  view on vc

Comment: You can achieve that by adding a `UITextField` in your `cell` and making its `inputView` a `datePicker` (you can drag-n-drop a `datePicker` to the Document Outline) - or a better option would be to implement like Apple has done in the [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple implements similar functionality in their [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866) example, as * Islam Q.* mentioned in a comment on your original question. However, for this answer, I'll assume you'd rather do what you described.

Your goal can actually be achieved with very little code.

- First, drag a `UIDatePicker` out onto a view controller in your
  Storyboard.
- Then, connect that date picker to an `IBOutlet` in the
  implementation of your view controller subclass.

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
  ```
- In that same view controller's `viewDidLoad()` (or `viewDidAppear(:)`, if that's more appropriate), move the date picker below the bottom edge of the screen by changing its frame. Don't animate the frame change. Nothing's onscreen anyway.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.datePicker.frame = self.offscreenFrame
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Next, in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`, animate `datePicker` back onto the screen. Right before you perform the animation, make sure to set the date picker's date to the current date.

  ```
  self.datePicker.date = UIDate()
  // now do the animation
  ```
- Finally, make sure to animate the dismissal of the date picker when appropriate (in `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)`, for example).

  ```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) { () -> Void in
      self.datePicker.frame = self.onscreenFrame
  }
  ```

Note that the actual implementation of each of these bullet points can differ depending on your situation. Also, `offscreenFrame` and `onscreenFrame` are "imaginary" variables that I used to simplify the code snippets.